How to set JsonElement value
I want to create a generic method to mask password properties inside a json document. How can I set the element value?
private void MaskPassword(string json)
{
    var node = JsonNode.Parse(json);
    if (node is JsonArray)
    {
        var arr = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonArray>(json);
        foreach(var item in arr)
        {
            MaskPassword(item.ToJsonString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var document = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonDocument>(json);
        foreach (JsonProperty property in document.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
        {
            if (property.Name.Contains("password", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                property.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.String)
            {
                var strValue = property.Value.GetString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue))
                {
                    property.Value = new string('*', strValue.Length); //how to set the value here?
                }
            }
        }

        json = document.RootElement.ToString();
    }
}


You cannot set the value of a JsonElement because it is read-only.  You must use an alternative API such as JsonNode.  See Modifying a JSON file using System.Text.Json.  Does that answer your question, or do you need a more specific answer showing how to fix your code specifically?

Or actually, you are already using JsonNode.Parse(json); Why are you also using JsonDocument and JsonELement?

You are mixing objects from the JsonNode and JsonDocument APIs, but JsonDocument is read-only and so cannot be modified.  See Modifying a JSON file using System.Text.Json for confirmation.
Instead it would be better to parse to JsonNode then recursively descend the node hierarchy, modifying the values of *password* properties as you find them:
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string? MaskPassword(string json, bool descendNested = true) => 
        MaskPassword(JsonNode.Parse(json), descendNested)?.ToString();
    
    public static JsonNode? MaskPassword(JsonNode? node, bool descendNested = true)
    {
        if (node is JsonArray array)
        {
            foreach(var item in array)
            {
                MaskPassword(item, descendNested);
            }
        }
        else if (node is JsonObject obj)
        {
            // We cannot modify obj while iterating though it, so make a list of replacements to set later
            List<(string Key, string Value)>? replacements = default; 
            foreach (var property in obj)
            {
                if (property.Value is JsonValue value)
                {
                    if (property.Key.Contains("password", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        && value.GetValueKind() == JsonValueKind.String)
                    {
                        var strValue = value.GetValue<string>();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue))
                        {
                            // TODO: this masking algorithm leaks information, specifically the password length.
                            // Decide whether to replace all passwords with some fixed length string instead.
                            (replacements ??= new()).Add((property.Key, new string('*', strValue.Length)));
                        }                       
                    }
                }
                else if (property.Value != null && descendNested)
                {
                    // If you want to recursively descend the hierarchy, do so here:
                    MaskPassword(property.Value, descendNested);
                }
            }
            if (replacements != null)
                foreach (var item in replacements)
                    obj[item.Key] = item.Value;
            
        }
        return node;
    }
}

Notes:

The optional parameter bool descendNested = true controls whether the method will descend into nested objects looking for passwords to mask.

Your masking algorithm new string('*', strValue.Length) leaks information about the password, specifically its length.  You may wish to replace the variable-length string with a fixed string.

The documentation page How to use a JSON document object model in System.Text.Json offers some guidance about when to use JsonNode vs JsonDocument.  It notes:


JsonDocument provides the ability to build a read-only DOM by using Utf8JsonReader...

JsonNode and the classes that derive from it in the System.Text.Json.Nodes namespace provide the ability to create a mutable DOM.



So JsonNode is the one to use here.


Demo fiddle here
